# Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise/Professional Error in Windows 7 Enterprise Service Pack 1

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am getting following error while installing VS 2015 in Windows 7 Enterprise Sp1. My machine already have 2012, 2013 with latest updates.

[image]

I dont know what is the issue here. I looked at the log file , but not found anything. And since my machine has Windows 7 Enterprise, I can't install windows updates manually.

Help me on this....Thanks in advance.